# Accessing different parts of brain for creativity

Tags: creative-writing

OK. So, here's the thing.

Some writers (e.g. Hemingway, Fitzgerald, Parker, others,) used alcohol. I cannot help but notice that I love all of them.

Completely sober, I am asking you, and not endorsing, a dangerous question.

Why do artists drink, and is there a level of artistry that is released through intoxication?

Is this ever suggested as a means to the craft? Ever?

Comment: If you get overboard with creativity, readers would ask: "What the author was smoking?", but not "What the author was drinking?" So, drinking must me a more conservative approach :)

Comment: Intoxication lowers inhibitions. If you have to get drunk to write because you're afraid of creating sober, you're too tightly wound. I recommend therapy rather than whiskey.

Comment: It sounds like you are both saying that what is written after drinking is different than what is written without drinking, so the answer is ... maybe?

Comment: I personally have 0 experience with being under the influence whilst creating, and everyone says I'm very talented. I honestly don't see why anyone would need to be intoxicated as an artist, unless maybe you're creating something that triggers a traumatic event.

Comment: That's interesting. I think everyone is probably very different. Wired differently. I focus heavily on mechanics, to the exclusion of connectivity. It seems that this tendency can be an impediment, but that does not mean I am endorsing anything. I have been struck sometimes by the number of artists that use one sort of mechanism or another.

Comment: Also, take into consideration the times as well. You're talking about an era where getting soused was not only accepted, but also, in some cases, expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confusing cause and effect.

Perhaps it is the rigors of life, faced courageously, with the open eyes of an artist, which drove these authors to both the bottle and the pen.

Do some research on the lives of great authors and you will find that hardship and pain are the traits shared almost universally.

Alcohol, when present, is there to comfort the writer.  Not to enrich the art.

Comment: I think all of these answers are part of it. I'm picking this one, but it's a toss up.

Answer (score 3):

There's no record Hemingway ever said "write drunk, edit sober." In fact, his granddaughter swears he only ever wrote sober ([1](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/booknews/10236200/Ernest-Hemingway-never-wrote-drunk-says-granddaughter-Mariel-Hemingway.html)).

Writing drunk feels good because it shuts off your internal critic. The words just flow out of you.

But booze also dulls your senses. To write compelling prose you need to be able to feel.

The best way to figure out what's right for you is to experiment. But I'd predict the results will be mixed at best.

By all means get drunk, get stoned. There's value in experiences like that. Don't write drunk and stoned though. The goal is to find out how to shut off your internal critic without needing alcohol. Then you can really write.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, alcohol is a psychoactive drug. If you drink a bottle of wine next time you sit down to write, you’ll probably write a little differently to usual.

What alcohol does to the brain [1]:

- Suppresses and releases certain neurotransmitters to slow down
  motor functions. Movement and speech are going to become sluggish. So
  that’s your typing (fix typos tomorrow, it’s fine!), and possibly
  part of your thought process gone a bit messy.
- Suppresses centres of the cerebral cortex that control thought, consciousness, and the senses. So while your inhibitions will be lowered, you’ll have more trouble thinking straight.
- Acts on the medulla, which controls automatic functions such as consciousness, thus making you sleepy. You might fall asleep at your desk!
- Increases dopamine to make you feel happy! Perhaps this will affect the tone of your writing. More likely, it will just make you want to keep drinking.

I don’t really see any of these contributing to increased *creativity*, though. So, how about you have a bottle of wine *every* time you sit down to write? Soon enough you might develop an alcohol dependency. As an addict, you might have a new way of thinking (brain shrinkage, deficiencies in fibres carrying information between brain cells), a new perspective on life (mental health problems), and a new purpose (staying drunk). All that stuff’s pretty likely to affect your writing, too. Maybe it will inspire different sorts of stories, themes, and tones from you (creativity?). Maybe it will just make writing, and life, a lot harder.

My point is, with these guys, I don’t think they were using alcohol to unlock anything. They were just addicts - they probably struggled to do many things without drinking. Of course that contributed something to their works, but it depends what it is about them all that you admire. Profundity? Melancholy? Suffering? Dark humour? Do you think that state of mind was reached by being drunk, or by virtue of being an alcoholic and the lifestyle and struggles that come with it? Or is it just that they were good writers, who happened to be alcoholics?

As for *why* they drink, I don’t believe it’s relevant. Some artistic people struggle which such things, some have other reasons. Again, I don’t think the purpose was to improve their writing. That's just how alcoholism works.

And is it suggested? From the above, I can’t imagine so. For creativity, a hallucinogenic might be a better bet.

[1] http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/inside-the-mind/human-brain/alcoholism4.htm